# Problems with jQuery UI tabs and children UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having some trouble with jQuery UI tabs. I'm using the default tab markup:

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
</div>
```

However, i want to display a list before my tabs. Like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <ul>
        <li>asdasdasd</li>
        <li>asdasdasd</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
</div>
```

And i don't want this list to be recognized as tabs. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put them before the `div#tabs` as the jQuery UI tabs functionality looks at all `li` in the `div` as far as I know.

Comment: Anyway i can modify that? Maybe grab only OL's for tabs, instead of UL's?

Comment: Not that I know of, I've tested it here (http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/Eppfy/) but it doesn't work. If you put it after the `ul` it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ?

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <ul>
        <li>asdasdasd</li>
        <li>asdasdasd</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <div id="content">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
       <ul>
           <li>asdasdasd</li>
           <li>asdasdasd</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this one i've not tested it

Comment: Not an option. It has to be inside that DIV. I'm using a very limited CMS. :(

Comment: test it with the div inside the tabs maybe it works, i didn't test it